# How can I get the White Western Star back to the garage for the Fixer Upper task?

Tags: snowrunner

There's a broken down White Western Star 4964 located in Smithville Dam which is part the Fixer Upper task. If you can repair and refuel and then bring haul it back to the garage, then you'll be given ownership of it. Sounds easy enough, except it's located just off a river, surrounded by a bunch of hills.

I've tried hauling this back for hours, and to no success. There's three hills near by that I've tried hauling it up, but to no success. I've seen others online talking about hauling it up these hills, but I either eventually get the truck on the environment, or I reach a point where I just can't haul it up any further.

I even tried selling all my trucks in exchange for a heavy truck, since I thought I'd have more success with that, but I just ended up getting the White Western Star stuck on a tree, and then ended up knocking my heavy truck over (Aka I gave up in defeat).

The best solution at this point might be to give up and come back to this later, but I'm far too stubborn for that... how can I haul the White Western Star 4964 back to the garage and complete the Fixer Upper task?

Comment: This isn't comprehensive enough for an answer of its own. I skipped ahead and retrieved the "Tartan" APC in Russia an brought it back to Michigan. That vehicle can pull anything. I winched the White Western Start and drove straight back to the garage. The mud didn't slow me down at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trial and error I finally completed this task, and since I know I'm not the only one struggling with it, I present to you my solution. Complete with freehand circles!

But first, let me just say that you shouldn't bother trying to go up with the hills. I know that seems to be the route everyone else is taking, but I also think that's why everyone is struggling so much with this task. I'm sure some folks can get up these hills no problem, but alas, I'm not that good of a hill trucker. If you're absolutely determined to use the hills for some reason, then wait until you've got access to a good Heavy Crane vehicle, since I've seen a few folks online saying that made the task easy.

### Suggested route

I didn't have a heavy crane yet though, and since I'm confident I'm not the only one in that position, I suggest the following path which completely avoids the hills:

[image: Fixer Upper Snowrunner Path]

Instead of going up the hills, you drag it alongside the river, and then climb up the hill from the northern side. Once you're up there, you'll want to cut through the woods and down a hill, which will take you right next to the start of the "Find the Antenna Tower" task. Going downhill here might seem like a recipe for disaster, but it was actually really easy. The only tricky part that once you're at bottom of the hill, it's a tight turn to get back on the side, so be careful not to get stuck on a tree. Top of the hill is pictured below.

[image: Hill shortcut]

From here you'll want to proceed the River Crossing (1), which is right next to the "Lost Bags" task. This is probably the first tricky part of the route, simply because if you get stuck in the middle of the river, you likely won't be able to winch yourself out. I had no problem getting across, and I tried to mostly follow the drowned road (which you'll see labeled on the in-game map).

Once you're past the river, then you should have a fairly easy time until you get to the following location cliffside location (2):

[image]

This is far and away the most dangerous part of the route. It's a fairly narrow road, right alongside a cliff, with a tight turn. The other side of the road has some trees and boulders, if you get White Western Stuck here, the cliff might result in you having a hard time freeing it. So long as you drive carefully though, you should get through without issue. I'd strongly suggest having the White Western Star winched right up against you, since it should reduce the risk of it getting stuck or falling off the cliff.

After this cliff, though, the rest of the route is really easy, and you'll connect to the highway very soon. Congrats, you did it!

#### Cavaets

There are a few caveats to this route though. For starters, it's really muddy, so you'll need a truck that's comfortable in the mud. I did it using the International PayStar 5070 with All Terrain Tires, which you can purchase from the shop (it's expensive, but you should be able to afford it by selling some trucks, which you can always just rebuy later). Even with a good mud truck you might still get stuck in the mud a few times, but you should be able to get the White Western Star across by dragging it  close to you with the winch, disconnecting, then advancing to some better ground and reconnecting the winch.

The other "gotcha" is that you'll actually need to complete a task to clear away from  boulders just past the gas station. I can't remember the name of this quest, but it's a really easy task. All you need are two Spare Service Parts (I might have the name wrong), which you can get at the Service Hub next to the garage.

Finally, it's all but guaranteed you'll need  to refuel during this route. I had to refuel twice with the Paystar, once before I took the hill shortcut near the "Find the Antenna Tower" task, and then again right after I crossed the river (1). I could probably have gotten by with just one refuel if I refueled right before the river crossing at (1), but better over fueled than stranded somewhere that's not easy for a refueling truck to reach.

### Alternate Route

So with all that said, if you're not a fan of this route, there is on alternate route you could try as well. Instead of cutting down the hill near "Find the Antenna Tower" task, you instead keep driving straight, and cut through the swamp. I didn't take this route  myself, but the folks online that were actually able to climb up the hills all seemed to take this route. There's no reason you couldn't still cut through the swamp but just skip the hill, and instead just cut alongside the river like I did. This swamp route seems waaaay longer than my route, but others have had success with it, so it's worth trying if you're not a fan of my route for some reason.

[image: westeran star alt route]

Answer (score 2):

### Shorter (by distance) route

There are no true shortcuts in this game. Figuring this out took me about 3 hours. However, it is absolutely possible to get up the hill to the West. Here is the route I used with points of interest labeled:

[image: Map outlining the approximate route taken]

First and foremost, you will need to fully repair and refuel the victim truck. **Do not attempt to refuel the victim truck until you have repaired the fuel tanks**. This may take a few trips, as the victim takes 300L of fuel and over 500 repair points plus 6 tires. This way, the truck will be able to move under its own power, which is necessary to get up some of the hills in question. This is not strictly necessary until you reach point of interest #2.

Additionally, you will need a heavy truck that performs well off-road. I used the International PayStar 5070, with support from an International LoadStar 1700. You do need a truck with good towing capability; the LoadStar was able to pull the victim truck some, but was not able to make it up the final hill.

Once the White Western Star is repaired and refueled, proceed along the route approximately as shown. The initial climb is not interesting until you reach the first left turn, POI #1 and #2:

1. There is a pair of rocks along the side of the road here, about 1 truck width apart. It is impassible while towing another truck.
2. There is a small lip at this point. In order to get over this, I had to tow the White Western Star backwards, so that the rear wheel drive of the White Western Star would engage on the other side of the lip, rather than being up in the air.

Congratulations, you're about halfway up. From here, things get a little tricky, but manageable if you know what you're doing.

3. There is a small valley filled with rocks in this region. Although it may kind of look enticing, and the closest way to the road, don't trust it. You will get stuck.
4. Proceed up the hill towards the power pole. This will get you away from the valley in #3. Once you're away from the valley, you can turn towards the road and start looking for an opening between the trees.

Congratulations, quest complete!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just take it right up the hill by threatening accident mission way faster. The trick is you just need to repair the truck first so it will drive by itself when you winch to it, just like you want to do with most trucks you find. Don't bother dragging either, find a service trailer or make a couple of trips with a scout or pickup truck with repair parts on a roof rack and repair the vehicles you find then tow them with the winch.

Answer (score 1):

repair it first then just pull it up the closests hill(north) to the main road, keep the winch line short. That way it will follow your driving line better, and make sure you stay on the road. did this in one try(when i tried it myself, when i tried it with my brother it went way different, but he was winching it). I think offroad truck is the best for this. last thing is don't follow the river path cut it short on the left-hand side where there are two smaller crossings.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the other answers, I was sure it didn't have to be so complicated. It wasn't: did it one shot, shortest possible route.
I made two trips with a maintenance frame add-on on the Fleetstar to fully repair and refuel the WWS. Then, winched it along the same way as I came down from the 'Threatening Accident' quest-point, but before the boulders bottle-neck, I climbed the hill to the right, towards the copse of trees. Not a hard climb. Got stuck in two places, but all I had to do was let the winch go, winch myself up and pull the WWS again. It worked and I was right near the dam.

Answer (score -3):

If you find a new vehicle all you gotta do is repair it and then get inside of it and recover to garage.

Comment: You can't actually do this for the mission vehicles like the White Western Star or the Hummer H2. You can for some vehicles like the Fleetstar next to the Black River garage, but not this one, you must tow it to the garage.

Comment: Yes of course Not for this one thats why i said you gotta repair it first then tow it with the winch so it drives under its own power when towing up the hill took me like 15 minutes to complete this way.